# How to fill a nan value in a column with value of column which has same values for other columns

Tags: python, pandas

[image]This is a problem from KPMG virtual internship

My question is how to fill nan values  job_industry column with values of job_industry of columns having a same job title

for example:

```
job_title               job_industry

Quality Engineer        Financial Services
Quality Engineer        Nan
```

I want the nan value for job_industry to be filled with Financial Services

like if a nan value is present at job_industry who job_title is General manager ,then fill it with Manufacturing

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal and executable example. For more information see [here](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports).

Answer (score -2):

I would start by creating a mapping (Python dict) between `job_industry` and `job_title` and then assigning the mapping of the column `job_industry` to the `NaN` values of job_title.

Here is the code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["job_title", "job_industry"],
    data=[["Quality Engineer", "Financial Services"], ["Quality Engineer", None]]
)

# May be there is a faster way
title_industry_mapping = df.dropna(["job_industry"]).set_index("job_title")["job_industry"].drop_duplicates().to_dict()

isna = df["job_industry"].isna()
df.loc[isna, "job_industry"] = df.loc[isna, "job_title"].replace(title_industry_mapping)
```

Result:

|  | job_title | job_industry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Quality Engineer | Financial Services |
| 1 | Quality Engineer | Financial Services |

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([
     ['Quality Engineer','Financial Services'],
     ['Progammer',np.nan],
     ['Quality Engineer',np.nan],
     ['Progammer',"IT"],
     ['General manager',np.nan]],
    columns=['job_title','job_industry'])
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_null', True):
    df = df.sort_values('job_industry', ascending=False, na_position='last')
df["job_industry"].loc[(df['job_title'] == "General manager") & (df['job_industry'].isnull())] = "Manufacturing"
df['job_industry'] = df.groupby('job_title')['job_industry'].fillna(method="ffill")
```

`df['job_industry'].isnull()`, this will verify `job_industry` column is null or not.

The following code will sort by null value in descending order of by the column job_industry,because if nan value appears before, the initial value of nan will not replace.

```
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_null', True):
    df = df.sort_values('job_industry', ascending=False, na_position='last')
```

if your prefer ordering to the output, you can try,`df.sort_index()`

**O/P**

```
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|    | job_title        | job_industry                                          |
|----+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 | Quality Engineer | Financial Services                                    |
|  1 | Progammer        | IT                                                    |
|  2 | Quality Engineer | Financial Services                                    |
|  3 | Progammer        | IT                                                    |
|  4 | General manager  | Manufacturing                                         |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Method 1 fills *all* positions as Financial Services. Method 2 does not work correctly if a position's first `job_industry` is null. Method 3 is just copied from my answer.

Comment: Yes, sure, you are answer is perfect, i already deleted the answer one time but i just put it for references where someone can adopt different methods and i just use fillna method only. And thanks

Comment: I removed all methods and updated accroding to question